# howto calculate the memory usage of a android.graphics.Path

Tags: android, memory-management

I am using an LRUCache to cache android.graphic.path objects. For that I need to know how many memory the pathes are using for overwriting the sizeOf() method of the LRUCache.

So my question is: How can I calculate the memory usage of a path ?

The difficulty what I already faced is:

- The android.graphic.path is not serializable
- path is probably stored as bitmap, what I read already ?

Primitivly measuring the memory usage as I did the following (Code) showed me confusing results. Example :

- a path with 10'000 lines uses 312 bytes.
- 10 pathes with 10 lines each uses 992 bytes.

Any hints ?

---

```
ArrayList<Path> alPathes=new ArrayList<Path>();
long iAnzahlBigPathes=1;
long iAnzahlOperation4BigPath=20000;

System.gc();System.gc();System.gc();System.gc();System.gc();System.gc();System.gc();System.gc();
long lused1=getUsedMemory();
Log.v("Memory4operation","ltotal1 " + lused1);// getMemoryStatus

for(int o=0;o<iAnzahlBigPathes;o++){
    Path path=getBigPath(iAnzahlOperation4BigPath);


    int iSize=path.toString().length();

    alPathes.add(path);
}
System.gc();System.gc();System.gc();System.gc();System.gc();System.gc();System.gc();System.gc();
long lused2=getUsedMemory();
Log.v("Memory4operation","ltotal2 " + lused2);// getMemoryStatus

long iDifferenz=lused2-lused1;
Log.v("Memory4operation", "Memory used for path " + iDifferenz + " in bytes");

//float fMemoryforoneline=(float)iDifferenz/(float)iAnzahlSquares;
float fMemoryforoneoperation=(float)iDifferenz/(float)iAnzahlOperation4BigPath/(float)iAnzahlBigPathes;
Log.v("Memory4operation", "" + fMemoryforoneoperation);


public long getUsedMemory(){
    final int ltotal = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
    final int lfree = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
    return (ltotal - lfree);
}

public Path getBigPath(long iAnzahlOperation4BigPath){

    int imin=10;
    int imax=1000000;
    Path path=new Path();
    path.moveTo(randInt(imin,imax),  randInt(imin,imax));
    for(int i=0;i<iAnzahlOperation4BigPath;i++){
        path.lineTo(randInt(imin,imax), randInt(imin,imax));
    }
    path.close();
    return path;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Path will usually use hardware rendering when available. So internally it's not stored as a Bitmap but a set of "drawing instructions".
You'll have to look at Path's underlying native implementations (SkPath.cpp) to see how exactly a path is stored internally.

There doesn't seem to be an API available to get the size of the Path.
You're left with:

1. Look at the implementation and estimate it yourself. Remember that if you save the Path Object to the cache you're caching the instructions and not the rendered result.
2. Render your path to a bitmap before putting it into the LRUCache. This will save you rendering time. Especially if your paths are expensive to draw. That's most likely what you want anyway